# I want to break loop

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
home_page.activityOnAgenda().then(function (items) {
       var len = items.length;
       for ( i = 0; i<=12;i++ ) {
           browser.element(by.xpath("//virtual-list/div/div["+len+"]")).click();
           browser.sleep(3000);
           var flag = false;
          home_page.activity("My Scrolling").isPresent().then( function (value) {
          if(value===true){
              break;}
          })

       browser.element(by.xpath("//virtual-list/div/div["+len+"]")).click();

   })
```

I am not able to use break statement  inside promise. If i use break statement outside promise then it doesn't execute if block which is outside for loop

Comment: Try using `return`

Comment: it won't work either as it's working synchronously where as the for loop will not wait for promise to fulfill

Comment: @priya make your `i` value greater than 12 inside the if as `i =13`.  so that the loop ends. Not sure whether this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async`/`await` to use sequential loops around promises:

```
const items = await home_page.activityOnAgenda();
const len = items.length;
for (let i=0; i<=12; i++) {
    await browser.element(by.xpath("//virtual-list/div/div["+len+"]")).click();
    await browser.sleep(3000);
    if (await home_page.activity("My Scrolling").isPresent()) {
        break;
    }
}
await browser.element(by.xpath("//virtual-list/div/div["+len+"]")).click();
```

If you can't use that syntax, either use a transpiler or go for a recursive approach that runs until it finds the element.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because functions can break loops which are in the function and not outside the function.
The `then` statement executes the function when the promise is resolved.
Here is an example.

```js
for (i = 0; i !== 10;i++){
  Promise.resolve(null).then(()=>{
    break
  })
}
```

This results in the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement
```

From the other answers to this question, you need to use `await`.
But it *should be* in a **async function**.

Valid `await`:

```js
(async function() {
  for (i = 0; i !== 10; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    let resolved = await Promise.resolve(1)
    if (resolved === 1) break;
  }
})()
```

Invalid `await`:

```js
  for (i = 0; i !== 10; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    let resolved = await Promise.resolve(1)
    if (resolved === 1) break;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't break the loop like this, because the `then` callback is **most likely** being executed only after the loop is done. If you really wanna break the loop using this callback, you can use `async/await`:

```
const items = await home_page.activityOnAgenda();
var len = items.length;
for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    browser.element(by.xpath("//virtual-list/div/div[" + len + "]")).click();
    browser.sleep(3000);
    var flag = false;
    const isPresent = await home_page.activity("My Scrolling").isPresent();
    if (isPresent) {
        break;
    }
    browser.element(by.xpath("//virtual-list/div/div[" + len + "]")).click();
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what the `browser` object is, but I bet it's `sleep` method is also async and needs `await`:

```
await browser.sleep(3000);
```